# Answer not associated with my login after migrating

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, migration, linked-accounts

My answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190002/who-is-your-number-one-guru-in-software-development-closed) question lost its connection with my ID after migrating [here](https://superuser.com/questions/13950/who-is-your-number-one-guru-in-software-development/13952#13952) to superuser.com. Although I have account on superuser.com associated with account on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I go to your user profile on superuser and check your [related accounts tab](https://superuser.com/users/723?tab=accounts#sort-top), I can see the association has **not** been made. It sais:

> No accounts matching this OpenID at
>   Stack Overflow
>
> No accounts matching this OpenID at
>   Server Fault
>
> No accounts matching this OpenID at
>   Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: Association was made on stackoverflow.com. Should it be bidirectional? Still I has associated it on superuser.com - no effect.

Comment: Associations should be bi-directional. e-mail team@stackoverflow if you've done all the associations and the question's still not linked.