# Automatically create accounts in all sister sites

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts, sister-site

I've seen a number of cases when questions have been migrated from one site to another (SO-->SF, SO-->SU etc).

If the original asker doesn't have an account on the site to which the question has been migrated, he basically loses track of the question.  This is especially true of questions that are migrated to SU which still needs a password having to do with [The Return of the Jedi](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/).

I suggest that once you have an account on one of the sites, you should also have an account in each of the sister sites so that you can easily keep track of all your questions that have been migrated.

**Edit:**  I know you can link the accounts.  I just think this should be automatic in order to reduce friction.

Comment: I think this is covered in this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/is-there-a-problem-with-creating-an-account-on-the-new-site-after-the-question-ha - though there hasn't been an announcement about the fix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automatically create accounts on all SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302979/how-do-i-automatically-create-accounts-on-all-se-sites)

Answer (score 11):

This question is quite old, and in the intervening years it's become much easier to create an account on a new site.  If you visit a site (while logged in) where you don't have an account, all you have to do is click "join this community" in the topbar and confirm.  (I'm not sure what the app equivalent is.)

We should never *automatically* create an account upon visit or migration, because there are good reasons that some people don't want accounts on some sites -- either at all, or visibly.  Instead of placing the burden of removing (or hiding) the account on the user -- i.e. making the user clean up something that was never asked for -- we should instead make it as easy as possible for the user to opt in and then get out of the way.

I don't think two clicks is too much to ask from users to join a community.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible if you're using Google's OpenID, as it uses a hash of the user's account and the identity of the requesting site to produce identity tokens. As such, your Google OpenID information is different on each site. The linked accounts system gets around this by having you log in separately with each site, thus establishing what your identity token is on the other domain.

I could see this being fixable if all the SO family sites proxied through an intermediate site to do authentication, but that won't help with accounts which already exist (indeed, it would render them unable to login).

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree.

I think that at the first visit on a sister site, a users must activate the account in order to disable phantom users from being a community members.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't accounts at the destination site already created in waiting when questions are migrated? (Or was that a misunderstanding and reading an answer here on Meta that doesn't exist?)

Tried [associating your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/answer-not-associated-with-my-login-after-migrating)?

[There's a bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites) in it for you if you do and have enough rep to juice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has become more of a problem in the recent years. Whilst using the app I can't seem to favorite a question if I don't have account on a particular SE site. It would be a great help if accounts on the sister sites are automatically created and linked up,  say the moment one wants to favorite a question,  or to comment or any other user action. These days many questions are pigeonholed to specific sites,  that seeing a question of interest on a site in which you don't have account is rather frequent occurance. [image: can't find user token]

Comment: This is  a bug. Joining a new site via the app should be transparent. What version you have?

Comment: I have version 1.0.89 for Android.

Comment: What exactly did you try to do that triggered that red banner? (e.g. did you try to post a comment, answer, vote?)

Comment: I just tried to favorite the displayed question.

Comment: The app should make it easy for you to create that account if you want, but nothing should *automatically* create an account.  Some people don't want accounts on some sites; we need to respect that.

Comment: Well, when you upvote you are given a popup letting you join the site with one click. Such popup does not appear for some reason when you favorite, which is either a bug or an oversight. Better start a new bug report/feature request asking to add this feature. /cc @Monica