# Android app error when posting an answer on a site you have never created a user on

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the navigation drawer and select **All Sites** option, it will show you all the Stack Exchange sites.
2. Select any site in which you haven't logged in yet (i.e., you are not member yet). For example, I have selected *Arqade*. As we have selected Arqade, it will load all the questions of this site.
3. Select any Question and navigate to Answer section.
4. Now try to post answer, it will give you below error message:

[image: screen shot]

### Issues:

1. Here user can post answer on any question on any Stack Exchange site. It should show me login page for the site which I haven't joined yet or simply it shouldn't allow me to post on that particular Stack Exchange site which I haven't joined yet.
2. As I have mentioned in 1st point it allows users to post answer on any site but I know the answer never going to be get posted on that particular site. Here it should show proper error message then. You can see improper error message "this error has been logged" by which no user can come to know what is the error exactly.

Comment: umm... as far as I know you _can_ answer anonymously on the smaller sites. Why should the android app be an exception?

Comment: @JanDvorak First of all, how can user come to know which site allows him/her to post on? Second, It should give proper error message if any occurs.

Comment: The title is kind of misleading. Add "Which he hasn't joined" at the end or something.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. The app should (eventually) allow seamless posting on a site you've never posted on before.

Comment: @David sadly enough looks like that more than three years later, [it still does not allow this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290192/152859). Guess it never will.

Answer (score 2):

If the user has not registered on a site then the android app should allow for them to register on that site and post as a member. I can't think of any good reasons to prevent someone from registering (or posting anonymously) on a stack exchange site from the android app when they can just launch a browser on the mobile device and register/post that way. Having a native app is supposed to make the user experience more friendly not to remove features that would be available if visiting the site from a browser on the same device.

Quick and simple the app should know if a user has permission to post before bringing up the editor (not counting changes that happen while typing up the post)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.0 the application handles site registration seamlessly or via a prompt, depending on the severity of the action you're doing, meaning that this bug has been fixed.