# Asking & Registering everywhere on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If I click on ask question, the only available websites are the one in which I currently have an account.

It would be nice for me to be able to ask a question anywhere and then be asked to register or at least be able to register on these sites form the app itself.

Comment: Please reply to this comment. (Testing and need a notification)

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as [this bug for posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192295/android-app-error-when-posting-an-answer-on-a-site-you-have-never-created-a-user) and your other bug for [commenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/error-when-commenting-or-answering-on-a-site-where-you-are-not-registered) this is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) for now.

I'm going to leave all the questions open since they're for separate parts of the same overarching feature-request.

Comment: Over two years later, any updates?