# Error when commenting or answering on a site where you are not registered

Tags: bug, android-app

When I try to answer a question on a site on which I don't have an account, it should be pointed out to me that I am currently not a member and it should bring me to a register page.

At the moment, if I try to answer or comment I get the following message :

> Please fix the following
>
> The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

Comment: No, I won't comment on your post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Answer (score 1):

This [alongside this other similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192295/android-app-error-when-posting-an-answer-on-a-site-you-have-never-created-a-user) are [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). We'll (hopefully soon) offer the ability to make users on other SE sites using the app which will fix them.