# Items in top bar become gray after selecting "edit" in the Your Communities section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open inbox, achivements and review popups from the top bar ... they look good yet.
2. Popup a list of all SE sites (right most button), click "edit" and leave it in this state:

> [image: se list]

3. Select any other menu ites ... all of them became gray:

   - Inbox

> [image: inbox]

- Achivements

> [image: achivements]

- Review

> [image: review]

This happens for old top bar too, but I noticed only after new bar is rolled out to localized SO sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Selectors in our JS for related function were not precise enough. Fix is now waiting in repo for next build.

Comment: [2 minutes from planning to implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K95KK.png) ... very good!

Comment: @alexolut well, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/error-when-commenting-or-answering-on-a-site-where-you-are-not-registered) is planned for over three years. And there are worse. This dev here actually means it when he puts the tag, unlike others. (Well, they might mean it when posting the tag, but then forget or more "urgent" things just keep popping up)