# I think my account is glitched on Quantum Computing SE

Tags: support, bug, linked-accounts

Usually when I join another network site on stack exchange, I start with 101 reputation because I have more than 200 reputation on another SE site.

Why do I have only 1 reputation in Quantum Computing though? Was this a bug?

Also, I just tried to ask this in Quantum Computing Meta, but I got the following error message (using the Android app):

> The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

(Not sure but this error might be related, perhaps my account was not fully associated).

Since I couldn't ask in Quantum Computing Meta, I decided to ask here.

Comment: Are you using the android app? In this case, it's dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/error-when-commenting-or-answering-on-a-site-where-you-are-not-registered.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I am. But I don't think it's a dupe, because I should be registered already.

Comment: Try browsing that site with a browser (not SE app) and click Join Community on top. This should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Using a computer browser, I went to my profile on Quantum Computing and clicked "delete profile". This way the "Join this Community" button appeared in the top right, so I clicked it, and now I have 101 reputation as expected.