# How do I automatically join all SE sites I haven't joined yet?

Tags: support, user-accounts, api

On SE sites which I haven't joined yet, neither inbox nor achievements are available. I'd like to have these available in all sites. I *could* wait around for the devs to fix it ... or I could join all sites. Even manually, that would probably finish sooner.

What's the quickest way to join all sites? Do I need to write a Stack App? The [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) doesn't seem to include an endpoint for joining a site. Ideally I'd like an account created on all sites I haven't joined yet, with these sites marked as hidden communities which I can then unhide at leisure.

---

I am not interested in asking SE to do it automatically for everybody. I'm asking what I can do on my end.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12571/270345

Comment: The only way to automate this is to write a userscript; there is no API support for account creation (thank Pete).  But to avoid spamming unused accounts, you might be smarter to just augment the inbox/achievements with a userscript, on sites where you aren't logged in.  The API *does* support that.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles but then I'd have to implement an entire inbox/achievements menu by myself, wouldn't I?

Comment: No, you'd just (re)add the buttons and tie them to API calls.  Pop up a very simple list of links, at a minimum. But displaying the results is not hard.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no, I'm not asking SE to do it for me, I'm asking what I can do to speed up the process.

Comment: Feels like potato potahto. It feels the same to me, and eh, its 1 of 5  Also, I think one of the CMs mentioned they need to join all the sites. And its manually.

Comment: That's sad. But I'd rather not roll over. It might be possible to use mechanize  or something to automate the click throughs. Or possibly somebody has already done it... in any case, not a feature request, not asking for any action from SE.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302996/270345

Comment: Not automated, but [here's a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628471/sites-where-a-user-doesnt-have-an-account-on) which lets you join all sites with just two clicks per site.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing a legitimate reason that a normal user would need to do this, apart from gaming the system...

Comment: @apaul ... Aside from getting back the inbox on all sites? I'd imagine the effort involved to recreate all the functionality of the inbox with a userscript and then maintain while SE devs go about breaking things would be less than the effort required to join all sites. As for gaming, I'm already a 100k on AU, 25k on U&L and an ex-mod-tempore. I don't have anything much to get from this except getting back some ease of use that was taken away.

Comment: also don't forget. There's new sites getting added (every so often?)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's trivial to watch area51 for new sites, I think they even have a feed for it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/launched (or is it http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/beta?)

Comment: @muru if you're spending enough time on another site to be worried about getting inbox notifications while you're there, would it really be that big a deal to join said site manually?

Comment: @apaul that's the thing. I'm not spending a lot of time on any one site, but I browse through enough HNQs that there's a cumulative effect.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense. I use the Android app purely for notifications, my phone makes noise when I get something new in my inbox, which reminds me to switch tabs or navigate back to one of my main sites.

Comment: @muru If you're logged in, you should be getting the inbox on all sites anyway. No need to have a user anymore.

Comment: @AdamLear I am logged in, and the new top bar doesn't show the inbox or achievements on sites I haven't joined. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302996/270345 for that feature request.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek since I have now written a userscript for this, there's a proper answer here now, and I'm going to flag that as a dupe of this.

Comment: @muru Ah, that looks like a regression then. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up writing a userscipt for this: (It's pretty crappy, but if anyone's interested in using it, I'd be happy to post on GitHub and take PRs.)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Autojoin
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Murukesh Mohanan
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var sites = [
        "https://writers.stackexchange.com",
        // fill up your own
    ];
    var site = $.cookie("se-autologin");
    if (site) {
        var next = $.cookie("next");
        if (next == "done") {
            return;
        }
        console.log("autologin", site);
        if (window.location.pathname == "/users/join") {
            $.cookie("next", "next", {
                path: "/",
                expires: 1
            });
            console.log("autologin", "join");
            document.querySelector('#confirm-submit').click();
            return;
        }
        if (next == "next") {
            $.cookie("next", "done", {
                path: "/",
                expires: 1
            });
            window.location.href = sites[sites.indexOf(window.location.origin) + 1];
        }
        return;
    }
    var ctas = document.querySelector('.-ctas a');
    if (ctas) {
        $.cookie("se-autologin", window.location.host,  {
            path: "/",
            expires: 90
        });
        ctas.click();
    }
})();
```

Use [Glorfindel's query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628471/sites-where-a-user-doesnt-have-an-account-on) to get the list of sites you haven't joined, manipulate it to fill the `sites` array, visit the first site and ... wait.

Pitfalls:

- the SEDE query doesn't return the canonical URL for some sites:

  ```
    "https://Garage.StackExchange.com/users/join|Join StackExchange.Garage","",""
    "https://avp.StackExchange.com/users/join|Join StackExchange.Audio","",""
    "https://Vegetarian.StackExchange.com/users/join|Join StackExchange.Vegetarian","",""
    "https://Beer.StackExchange.com/users/join|Join StackExchange.Beer","",""
    "https://Moderators.StackExchange.com/users/join|Join StackExchange.Moderators","",""
  ```

  This causes the script to stop because it can't find the canonical URL in the sites array. In those cases, I had to manually proceed to the next site.
- Leaves behind stale cookies.

---

And:

[image]

---

Hiding these sites is an entirely different problem. The path to that particular preference page is easy: `/users/hidecommunities/current`. However, simply setting the value of the search field isn't enough to activate the button. Any hints here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As @MonicaCellio says in her [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290223/215590) to [Automatically create accounts in all sister sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12571):

> I don't think two clicks is too much to ask from users to join a community.

so I think just clicking to join each community at the time when you actually wish to participate in it makes sense, and should remain as the quickest way to join any/all sites.

Comment: ~170+ sites, ~45 I have joined ... so that's ~125*2 = 250 clicks, plus all the time it takes to load each site's page, the confirmation pages, the strain on my fingers... nope.

Comment: @muru but the problem arises when you actually *visit* one of those sites, so you don't need to do it in advance.  Arrive at new site, notice missing inbox/notifications, click "join" and confirm, problem solved for that site.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: @MonicaCellio an eminently automatable action, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Sure, but worth the cost?  One *could* write a Greaemonkey script that detects "site I don't have an account on" and fixes that, but you'll only need it about a hundred times and the script will run on every page load, *plus* you need to write the script.  I'd find it easier to just create the accounts as I go, personally.  (I have a lot of accounts that exist only because I needed to flag something; so far this approach has worked fine for me.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio never mind. I went ahead and wrote it.