# Always show inbox and achievements in the top bar, without requiring an account on each site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

On a site where I do have an account, the left part of the top bar looks like this:

[image]

On SE sites where I don't have an account, the user information and review queue icon is obviously missing, but also the inbox and the achievement dropdowns.

[image]

The user avatar, reputation and badges are obviously information tied to this specific site, so it makes sense that they're missing. The same goes for the review queue, as I can't review without creating an account.

But the inbox and the achievement dropdowns are *global* features. They're the same on every SE site, and they display information from all sites you're active. It doesn't make any sense that they're suddenly missing just because you're looking at a site where you don't have an account.

To me it would make much more sense to always show the inbox and achievement icons on all sites, and to move the "Join this community" banner into the place where the user information usually is.

Comment: Moving the "join this community" is [tag:status-declined], see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301925/270345

Comment: Yeah, the inbox and the achievements dropdowns are supposed to be there. Their absence is just an `if` check gone wrong. We'll fix that up.

Comment: Oddly enough, the mobile site works fine for once: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bz3y.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8gy2.png

Comment: This [appears to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmySj.png) implemented.

Comment: @AdamLear [tag:status-completed], then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix rolled out yesterday along with the updated top bar on stackexchange.com. Apologies for the omission in the first place... it was not intentional.