# I answered a question on one meta, and it got migrated to another meta, but I was not associated with the answer!

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, migration

I answered [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137762/what-constitutes-a-subjective-question-on-superuser-com?noredirect=1)

And it was migrated to [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5080/72053), but I have been dissociated with the answer!

How do I get [my name](https://meta.superuser.com/users/72053/neal) back on that answer?

Comment: A meta-meta question?

Comment: @Oded [indeed](http://youtu.be/XtPgr94VYA4)

Comment: Do you use the same login credentials on both sites?

Comment: @AlEverett I use the same login credentials throughout the Stack Exchange ^_^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answer not associated with my login after migrating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/answer-not-associated-with-my-login-after-migrating)

Comment: @AlEverett That is a different localized case yes, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Did you try logging out of meta.SU & logging back in? I think that (or just the time it took to do that possibly) fixed something like that for me once.

Comment: @Mat That seemed to do it! Thanks :-).   I wonder ***why*** that worked though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in a build rolling out in a few minutes.

A bug with migrations *to* child metas in general (they're relatively very rare) was the root cause here.  The user lookup was basically FUBARed for *everyone* in this case.  This build fixes that issue and a few *possible* others that I've yet to actually see in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

I did what @Mat said in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137765/i-answered-a-question-on-one-meta-and-it-got-migrated-to-another-meta-but-i-wa/137766#comment386326_137765) --

> Did you try logging out of meta.SU & logging back in? I think that (or just the time it took to do that possibly) fixed something like that for me once.

Which surprisingly **worked**!

Comment: +1 me too :) I'd like to know the _why_ part though.

Comment: @Mat I [asked a question about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137769/155556)