# Why did I have to jump through hoops to get my migrated answer associated with my account?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, migration

When I got the answer for [I answered a question on one meta, and it got migrated to another meta, but I was not associated with the answer!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137765/155556) it was that I had to **log out** of meta.SU and then log back in, and then *magically* the answer was associated with my account.

Why did I have to go through those steps to associate the answer?

What went on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The re-association of posts on login is an ancient safety feature, really in place for when you *first* register on a site, but left in as a fallback for cases just like this.

Why didn't your post associate in the first place?  Because child metas aren't in our central account database, only the parent site needs an entry there...and this caused issues with the user lookup which goes through that route.  This issue is fixed in a build rolling out in a few minutes.